# PHP Script causing server to run out of RAM and wont release

Tags: centos, php, memory

Ive been running a very resource hungry script the past 2 days. I manually trigger the call and it lasts for about 30 minutes then stops. Last night the script stalled when ram hit 100%.

I restarted the server and this was the status of the ram. Usually ram is around 300mb when its just running the single website hosted on the site.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048        150       1897          0          0         32
-/+ buffers/cache:        118       1929
Swap:          128          0        128
```

I have run the script a few times today and i have been checking the ram as it has been running and its slowly eating up RAM, but not releasing it when the script finishes. I can understand the spike when the script is running, but after the script finishes and i leave it for 20 mins ram stays the same.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048       1522        525          0          0        182
-/+ buffers/cache:       1339        708
Swap:          128          0        128
```

Why is the script eating up all this memory and not releasing it?

This is what the script is doing.
It will select 100 rows from a database table. It will then take the data and get data from 5 different RESTful JSON APIs. 3 of these APIs just involve parsing text and inserting it into database tables. 2 involve parsing text and copying images. These images are copied to the hard disk and then i compress and re-size them using PHP.

Once all 100 rows have been processed the script stops and thats the end of it. Its intensive, but i dont understand why the memory isnt being released after it finishes.

can anyone help? I have a linux vps running centos with 2gb of ram.

Comment: It might be better to ask why the script uses up so much memory at all?

Comment: its processing images which is gonna be tough. i do destroy the image objects after writing them though. Are there any tips you can give me to help reduce the amount im using or even better debug the issue and find out whats eating it all up and not giving it back?

Comment: What version of PHP is this? And what is the setting of `zend.enable_gc` in `php.ini`?

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.29. I cant find an reference to zend.enable_gcin the php.ini. var_dump(gc_enabled()); returned true when i ran it in a script

Comment: Doesn't sounds like a server problem. But it does sound like there is a massive memory leak in the script. You might want to share the script at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) to see what other PHP devs have to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pin-point the real problem. We need to know what you are doing in the script. It might be as simple as putting all the requests in a queue and processing them one by one, using Cron. This way  you can also mark certain entries as "failed" and come back to see why those specific one's are running into issues. Please provide more info on what you are trying to process, so we can better advise on how to do that.